# VLC enqueue using batch file issues - Not playing next track if there's a break in the music

Tags: windows, batch-file, vlc

So, I'm writing a Jukebox program using Win7 that launches individual batch files depending on which track the user selects.

I have the following code that successfully loads each track into VLC:

```
VLC --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue --playlist-tree "2 Ed Sheeran  Thinking Out Loud.mp3"
```

If VLC isn't already open, the batch file opens it fine. (Success)

If VLC is already playing a track and you launch another batch file it will add it to the queue and play after the preceding track. (Success)

HOWEVER, if the playlist ends and you run a batch file, VLC just waits (paused). Pressing play on VLC isn't possible as it is being run hidden behind my jukebox program. (*And even if play was pressed it re-plays the last track from the old playlist before playing the new batch-run track*).

So I need either

- a modified batch, to enable a batch file to execute as if it was the first track (ie; just play the new selected track),
- a batch to close VLC if nothing is playing, (therefore the next batch that comes through re-opens VLC)
- or any other suggestions (bear in mind, it has to run with batch and I do require VLC to be the player).

Thanks in advance, any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could test with the --loop option set, could possibly fix your problem as long as the playlist always is the same playlist (with different content obviously)

Comment: Hey Melis, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, although this does stop VLC from going into pause mode, once the playlist is finished it'll play the entire list from the start. So if the jukebox had had 50 songs selected and then nothing for a while, the tracklist will obviously repeat, meaning anyone that added a new track would have to wait for 40+ songs to play before their choice was played. Thanks again though, heading in the right direction :)